# Install jdk in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, java

I installed java from a binary package (bin format). Now I want to know how to set environment variables in Linux (Ubuntu).

Nothing happend when I type set `path=<location of bin folder>`.

Then how to run a `.jar` app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. for configuration

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME="jdk/installation/dir"
   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME"/bin"
   ```
2. For running `something.jar`

   ```
   java -jar something.jar
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just install the OpenJDK from the Ubuntu Software Center. Much less of a hassle.

PS: Do you actually want the JDK, or do you just want to run a .jar? (cause that's how I interpret the second part of your question).

Because you will very likely already have a JVM if you're using Ubuntu, you could just type

```
java -jar /path/to/thejar.jar
```

Comment: Jvm is not included in ubuntu it is to be downloaded from ubuntu software centre
* i need jdk because i have to learn java pgming

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use `javac` commend in terminal to see whether you have installed sdk properly. If answer is no, define paths. And it would be better if you had explained something about IDE, which IDE you will use.. MAy it be easy